# Trying to add sum of all even integers between 2 and the input, and I just get the input back

Tags: java, loops

I'm attempting to write something for an assignment that takes the sum of all the even integers between 2 and the number entered by the user and prints it. If it is below 2 it should return an error. I'm getting an error for anything under 2, however, when I go have it return the sum it just returns the input.

I think I may have messed a variable up in this loop, but I can't see where I went wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EvenSum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number larger than 2");
        int num = input.nextInt();
        if (num >= 2) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 2; i <= num; i +=2) {
                sum += i;
            }
            System.out.println("The sum of all even numbers between 2 and the input is " + num);
                } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid, please enter a number above 2");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.out.println("The sum of all even numbers between 2 and the input is " + num);
```

should be

```
System.out.println("The sum of all even numbers between 2 and the input is " + sum);
```

There is a formula to compute the answer without a loop, by the way.  But perhaps that is not the point of the exercise?

Comment: Yea our assignment is to practice writing loops so I assume my professor wants it written as a loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you return `num` instead of `sum`

Answer (score 0):

Declare `sum` outside if statement, and print `sum` instead of `num`

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class EvenSum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number larger than 2");
        int num = input.nextInt();

        int sum = 0;
        if (num >= 2) {

            for (int i = 2; i <= num; i += 2) {
                sum += i;
            }
            System.out
                    .println("The sum of all even numbers between 2 and the input is "
                            + sum);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid, please enter a number above 2");
        }
    }
}
```